# No curve drawn with bodegraph

Tags: gnuplot, bodegraph

I'm trying to plot a Bode diagram with the `bodegraph` package, but the curve is not shown. I don't know what to do.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[gnuplot def/.append style={prefix={}},xscale=7/4]
\begin{scope}[yscale=2.5/100]
\semilog{-2}{2}{-40}{60}
\BodeGraph[thin,samples=100]{-1.5:1.5}
{\POAmpAsymp{8}{0.5}+\IntAmp{1}}
\BodeGraph{-1.5:1.5}{\POAmp{8}{0.5}+\IntAmp{1}}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm,yscale=2.5/200]
\OrdBode{20}
\semilog{-2}{2}{-200}{0}
\BodeGraph[samples=100,thin]{-2:2}
{\POArgAsymp{8}{0.5}+\IntArg{1}}
\BodeGraph{-2:2}{\POArg{8}{0.5}+\IntArg{1}}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It just red grids with no blue curve like the attached picture.

Answer (score 3):

If I run your example, named `test.tex`, with

```
pdflatex test
```

I indeed get no picture, but four files called `1.gnuplot`, `2.gnuplot`, `3.gnuplot` and `4.gnuplot` are written out.

You need to run `gnuplot` over them and rerun `pdflatex`. Or, more easily, run

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test
```

so `gnuplot` will be called during the LaTeX run.

[image]

Note that you need `gnuplot` on your system to begin with. From the package manual:

> Les commandes de tracés nécessitent que `gnuplot` (http://www.gnuplot.info/) soit installé et utilisable par votre distribution LaTeX.

English translation:

> Plotting commands require that `gnuplot` (http://www.gnuplot.info/) be installed and usable by your LaTeX distribution.

Comment: I'm using ``texlive`` for typesetting and I run the MWE with ``pdflatex`` but it's still just two red grids.

Comment: @H.H You need to enable `-shell-escape` and also to have `gnuplot` available on your system.

Comment: I have enabled ``-shell-escape`` already. how can I see whether ``gnuplot`` is available or not?

Comment: @H.H Look in the log file, you should see what happens: look for `runsystem`. What's your operating system?

Comment: I have ``TeXLive`` on ``windows``.

Comment: @H.H See http://www.gnuplot.info

Answer (score 0):

I come across the same problem with you.Finally I solve this by following this:

> PGF/TikZ provides a convenient mechanism for plotting functions using `GNUPLOT`_. To run this example for the first time you have to
>   do the following:
>
> - GNUPLOT must be installed on your system. Try typing `gnuplot` on the command line to   see if it's installed. Windows users may have to
>     rename `wgnuplot` to `gnuplot`.
> - You must allow TeX to run external programs. The command line option to enable this is   usually `--shell-escape` or `--enable-write18`
>     PGF will call GNUPLOT for you and store the data in a file. Next time
>     you compile the example, data will be loaded from the generated file.
>     See section 11.12.3 in the manual for  more information.

They come from the example file here http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/gnuplot-basics/

If you use VS code, you can refer to this([VS Code - Latex Workshop - custom recipes file location](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478865/vs-code-latex-workshop-custom-recipes-file-location)) to enable the `--shell-escape`.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.